# Memory leak issue in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak with TensorFlow 1.14. I referred to various GitHub issues and [Memory leak with TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327803/memory-leak-with-tensorflow) to address my issue, and I followed the advice of the answer, that seemed to have solved the problem. However it does not work here. I even ported the code to Tensorflow 2.1 and 2.3 but still could not solve the problem.

Whenever I load the model then memory leak is there. I tried to clear the session after the model is loaded and used garbage collect API also but leak still persists.

In order to recreate the memory leak, I have created a simple example. I have used below function to check the memory used of the python process.

```
def memory_usage_func():
    import os
    import psutil
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem_used = process.memory_info()[0] >> 20
    print("Memory used:", mem_used)
    return mem_used
```

Below is the function to load the model and check memory usage:

```
for i in range(100):
    model = load_model('./model_example.h5', compile=False)
    del model
    memory_usage_func()
```

In above code, memory leak issue persists. Further, I tried to do prediction. For that, I created a session, load the model and run predict(). There also I face same memory leak issues. I used `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` and `gc.collect()` after model is loaded. But, it is unable to clear the session and free the memory.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution to this? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue when I tried to use pre-trained embedding model to generate embedding as input feature set. While using universal-sentence-encoder-4, memory used for generate embedding is not released. Neiether `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` nor `gc.collect()` helped.

I ended up using `multiprocessing` module to start a 'subprocess' to repeat

1. do something with multiprocess
2. kill process (memory is released)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def get_embedding(model_dir, text, q):
    print("      loading encoder")
    encoder = hub.load(model_dir)
    print("      generate embedding")
    encoded = encoder(text).numpy()
    print("      returning embedding")
    q.put(encoded)


manual_wait_time = 20

## for iterate
q = mp.Queue()
p = mp.Process(target=get_embedding, 
args=(encoder_dir, some_text, q, ))
p.start()
## p.join() ## hangs forever see reference
time.sleep(manual_wait_time)
print("manually wait %s seconds"%manual_wait_time)
embedded_mini_batch = q.get()
q.close()
p.terminate()
```

references:

- [How do i use subprocesses to force python to release memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937189/how-do-i-use-subprocesses-to-force-python-to-release-memory)
- https://sopython.com/canon/82/programs-using-multiprocessing-hang-deadlock-and-never-complete/
- [Process.join() and queue don't work with large numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708646/process-join-and-queue-dont-work-with-large-numbers)