# Memory leak in Tensorflow

Tags: keras, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, tensorflow2.0

I am creating and discarding a large number of neural network models in a loop. Somehow, discarded models accumulate in memory and eventually cause an out-of-memory crash.

The command `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` is supposed to avoid clutter from old models ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clear_session)). However, the command is not working for me.

Tensorflow version: 2.8.0
Keras version: 2.8.0

Minimal example to reproduce:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Use GPU
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
print("physical devices: ", physical_devices)
# Don't crash if something else is also using the GPU
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

def create_nn_model():
    """initialize and return a nn model"""

    Ndim = 100
    N_nodes_L1 = 1000
    N_nodes_L2 = 5000

    # construct model
    x_input = keras.Input(shape=[Ndim])
    L1 = keras.layers.Dense(N_nodes_L1, input_shape = [Ndim],
                                     activation="swish")(x_input)
    L2 = keras.layers.Dense(N_nodes_L2, input_shape=[N_nodes_L1],
                                     activation="swish")(L1)
    output = keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[N_nodes_L2],
                                   activation = "linear")(L2)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=[x_input],
                        outputs = [output])
    # plot model
    keras.utils.plot_model(model, "model.png", show_shapes=True)
    return(model)


for ii in range(1_000):

    print(f"Training model {ii+1} of 1,000")
    nn_model = create_nn_model()

    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```

Error message:

```
2023-06-21 18:35:33.887623: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:462] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 19.07MiB (rounded to 20000000)requested by op AddV2
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation.
Current allocation summary follows.
Current allocation summary follows.
2023-06-21 18:35:33.887904: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1010] BFCAllocator dump for GPU_0_bfc
2023-06-21 18:35:33.888881: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (256):       Total Chunks: 66, Chunks in use: 56. 16.5KiB allocated for chunks. 14.0KiB in use in bin. 228B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-06-21 18:35:33.889243: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (512):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-06-21 18:35:33.889709: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (1024):      Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 1.2KiB allocated for chunks. 1.2KiB in use in bin. 1.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-06-21 18:35:33.889982: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (2048):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-06-21 18:35:33.890294: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (4096):      Total Chunks: 199, Chunks in use: 198. 920.0KiB allocated for chunks. 912.2KiB in use in bin. 773.4KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-06-21 18:35:33.890487: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (8192):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.

...

2023-06-21 18:35:34.110374: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1074] 2 Chunks of size 33554432 totalling 64.00MiB
2023-06-21 18:35:34.110547: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1074] 1 Chunks of size 33741824 totalling 32.18MiB
2023-06-21 18:35:34.110718: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1074] 1 Chunks of size 34217728 totalling 32.63MiB
2023-06-21 18:35:34.111092: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1074] 1 Chunks of size 36870912 totalling 35.16MiB
2023-06-21 18:35:34.111263: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1078] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 3.87GiB
2023-06-21 18:35:34.111450: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1080] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 4162256896 memory_limit_: 4162256896 available bytes: 0 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 4294967296
2023-06-21 18:35:34.111627: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1086] Stats:
Limit:                      4162256896
InUse:                      4160154112
MaxInUse:                   4160154368
NumAllocs:                        2972
MaxAllocSize:                 36870912
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2023-06-21 18:35:34.111869: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:474] ****************************************************************************************************
2023-06-21 18:35:34.112024: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1733] RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: failed to allocate memory
```

Apparently, [multiprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518432/memory-leak-issue-in-tensorflow) can serve as one possible workaround. However, it looks complicated and I would prefer a simpler solution if at all possible.

Comment: This is a persistent problem in tensorflow, I would say use gc.collect via callback at the end of a training epoch

Answer (score 0):

The memory leak is a known problem on [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50765) since July 2021, so two years by now.

Possible solutions:

1. Wait for the problem to be patched. It has been [partially](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50765#issuecomment-1608357890) but [not completely](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50765#issuecomment-1634226323) fixed in TensorFlow 2.12.
2. Downgrade to TensorFlow 2.5, which [does not have this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/57982).
3. Periodically save everything, restart the program, load everything, and resume training.
4. Switch to PyTorch.
5. Switch to Julia and use Flux.

Edit: As an example of solution 3, create an external script. This script will call your program with the memory leak (called main_leaky_script.py below), and automatically relaunch it when it crashes with no manual intervention from you. Launch the external script from an environment with TensorFlow installed:

```py
import os
import time

exit_code = 1
i = 0
MAX_RUNS = 100

while exit_code and i < MAX_RUNS:
    i+=1
    print(f"Step {i} of maximum {MAX_RUNS}")
    exit_code = os.system("python3 main_leaky_script.py")
    print("Exit code: ", exit_code)
    time.sleep(1)

print(f"Ended on run number {i} ({i+bool(exit_code)-1} crashes)")
```

At the start of your main_leaky_script.py, try to load the model and create it if it doesn't exist yet:

```py
try:
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.keras")
except:
    # initialize your model from scratch
    model = create_nn_model()

# Compile model
# Do training inside a loop, stopping and saving your model every few epochs. 
# To save, use the command:
model.save("model.keras")
```

It may be better to set up checkpoints and save and load weights instead of entire models. See the official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load) for more information.

Comment: is some oone find a real solution? I have the same problem using data.dataset to read multiple csv.... memory build up until crash

Comment: I updated the answer with a description of my solution. It's an ugly hack, but it works. The real solution is to switch to PyTorch.

Comment: did you use dataset to feed the model no stop? If yes check to remove  .cache() if you use it... it work for me

Comment: @jonathan Are you saying the crash was caused by something to do with your dataset? If so, then we have different problems. I get an out-of-memory crash from creating models, even when I don't have any data and don't do any training or predictions.

Comment: hoooo, my bad, my case was in trainning, memory build up until crash... but if your situation is in building model... it was realy strange..