# Python multiprocessing does not exit

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-2.x

I had a code that was running successfully, but takes too long to run. So I decided to try to parallelize it.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import time


output = mp.Queue()

def calcSum(Nstart,Nstop,output):
    pid = os.getpid()

    for s in range(Nstart, Nstop):
        file_name = 'model' + str(s) + '.pdb'

        file = 'modelMap' + str(pid) + '.dat'

        #does something with the contents of the pdb file
        #creates another file by using some other library:
        someVar.someFunc(file_name=file)

        #uses a function to read the file
        density += readFile(file)

        os.remove(file)

        print pid,s

    output.put(density)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    snapshots = int(sys.argv[1])
    cpuNum = int(sys.argv[2])

    rangeSet = np.zeros((cpuNum)) + snapshots//cpuNum
    for i in range(snapshots%cpuNum):
        rangeSet[i] +=1

    processes = []
    for c in range(cpuNum):
        na,nb = (np.sum(rangeSet[:c])+1, np.sum(rangeSet[:c+1]))
        processes.append(mp.Process(target=calcSum,args=(int(na),int(nb),output)))

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    print 'now i''m here' 

    results = [output.get() for p in processes]

    print 'now i''m there' 

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print 'think i''l stay around'
    t1 =time.time()
    print len(results)
    print (t1-t0)
```

I run this code with the command `python run.py 10 4`.

This code prints the `pid` and `s` successfully in the outer loop in `calcSum`. I can also see that two CPUs are at 100% in the terminal. What happens is that finally `pid 5` and `pid 10` are printed, then the CPU usage drops to zero, and nothing happens. None of the following `print` statements work, and the script still looks like it's running in the terminal. I'm guessing that the processes are not exited. Is that the case? How can I fix it?

Here's the complete output:

```
$ python run.py 10 4
now im here
9600
9601
9602
9603
9602 7
9603 9
9601 4
9600 1
now im there
9602 8
9600 2
9601 5
9603 10
9600 3
9601 6
```

At that point I have to stop termination with `Ctrl+C`.

A few other notes:

- if I comment `os.remove(file)` out, I can see the created files in the directory
- unfortunately, I cannot bypass the part in which a file is created and then read, within `calcSum`

**EDIT** At first it worked to switch `output.get()` and `p.join()`, but upon some other edits in the code, this is no longer working. I have updated the code above.

Comment: apply join() to them, I would guess

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I thought I already was. See the couple of lines below `print 'now i''m here'` in the code.

Comment: Aha, sorry missed it

Comment: Shouldn't you call join() AFTER output.get() ?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Yep, that did it. This is the first time I'm attempting parallel programming in python, and I was following an example online, which happens to be wrong I guess. The weird thing is, the other example was working without problem.

Comment: What about writing an answer? I'll endorse it

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I think you should write it. I wouldn't be able to explain why `join()` needs to be after `output.get()` anyway.

Comment: If you haven't already written the answer, I have a couple of recent dupes I think -- let me find them.

Comment: Would you say the problem is [similar to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665328/python-3-multiprocessing-queue-deadlock-when-calling-join-before-the-queue-is-em/31665635#31665635)

Comment: @PatrickMaupin It was, now upon changing some seemingly unrelated lines in the code, I still have the same error. I'm updating the code in the question.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux The same problem occurred when I changed a tiny bit of the code. Could you have a look?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Nevermind, I solved it. There was an indentation problem.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin Sorry, please ignore my previous comment. It was an indentation error. The problem is identical to the other question, so I'll mark it as a duplicate.