# Multiprocessing does not work and hangs on join on windows 10

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I was building a program to be deployed on windows. But I built it on Linux. I use multiprocessing and everything worked fine on Linux. But in windows, the processes do not run simultaneously and when they terminate, the program hangs in join statements. I read this was a known bug fixed on 3.7 but I am on 3.9.4.

The code:

```
def worker(day, queue, team, daily_jobs):
    print(f"process {day} started")
    initial_solution = solve_for_routes(
        len(team), daily_jobs[day])
    print(f"process {day} ended")
    queue.put([day, initial_solution])

def main(pools, workday=6):
 

    queue = multiprocessing.SimpleQueue()
    team = ["bir", "iki", "üç"]
    processes = []

    for day in daily_jobs:
        if not daily_jobs[day].empty:
            processes.append(
                multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(day, queue, team, daily_jobs)))

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    for _ in processes:
        q = queue.get()
        plan[q[0]] = q[1]

    named_plan = convert_to_named(plan, workday, team)

    return named_plan
```

It prints:

```
process 0 started
process 0 ended
process 1 started
process 1 ended
process 2 started
process 2 ended
process 3 started
process 3 ended
process 4 started
process 4 ended
process 5 started
process 5 ended
```

And the program just hangs never making it further the `join()`

Again, this works perfectly fine on Linux.

Comment: How do you execute your main()? That part of your code is missing.

Comment: You don't even need the `join`s.  All you care about is reading the results from the queue.  After you've read N results, you know the processes are done.

Comment: @Hannu I just call it with the parameters. Nothing unusual.

Comment: @Tim Roberts You're right but that's not the only issue. The processes execute in order rather than at the same time.

Comment: How do you know?  If the task is small and you don't have a plethora of processors, it's quite possible each finishes before the next starts.  If you put `time.sleep(5)` in the function, do you see the same result?

Comment: When I run your code, they run out of order.  I think it's working fine.

Comment: @Tim Roberts the processes take about 2 minutes each. I will try it without the joins anyway, just in case. So the multiprocessing should work out of the box in windows?

Comment: Yes.  I just ran your code on my Win 10 box, with stubs for your functions, and it worked fine.

Comment: @TimRoberts Well, removing the joins worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you could also use concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 Multiprocessing queue deadlock when calling join before the queue is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665328/python-3-multiprocessing-queue-deadlock-when-calling-join-before-the-queue-is-em). **Calling `join` is *not* the problem; it's *when* you are calling `join` that is the problem.**