# Multiprocessing.Queue hangs process when it is large enough

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

Today, I've stumbled on some frustrating behavior of `multiprocessing.Queue`s.

This is my code:

```
import multiprocessing


def make_queue(size):
    ret = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for i in range(size):
        ret.put(i)
    return ret


test_queue = make_queue(3575)
print(test_queue.qsize())
```

When I run this code, the process exits normally with exit code 0.

However, when I increase the queue size to 3576 or above, it hangs. When I send SIGINT to it through Ctrl-C, it raises the error here:

```
Exception ignored in atexit callback: <function _exit_function at 0x7f91104f9360>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/captaintrojan/.conda/envs/example_env/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 360, in _exit_function
    _run_finalizers()
  File "/home/captaintrojan/.conda/envs/example_env/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 300, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
  File "/home/captaintrojan/.conda/envs/example_env/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 224, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/captaintrojan/.conda/envs/example_env/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 199, in _finalize_join
    thread.join()
  File "/home/captaintrojan/.conda/envs/example_env/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1096, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/home/captaintrojan/.conda/envs/example_env/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1116, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    if lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Can anyone please explain this behavior? I've experimented with the sizes, indeed, from a sample of 40 or so different sizes, any size below or equal to 3575 works fine and any size above 3575 hangs the process. I figured it may have something to do with the queue size in bytes, because if I insert `i*i` or some random strings instead of `i`, the threshold changes. Note that, unless `multiprocessing.Queue` does something suspicious in the background, I don't create any additional processes other than the main process. Also, adding `test_queue.close()` has no impact on the outcome.

Comment: Generally, you can expect a process to not quit until all items it put in the queue are consumed. The anomaly here isn't when the size is >3575 (that is the [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines), expected behaviour), it's when the size is less than that and the process still successfully quits. Some context on why that happens and how it varies from machine to machine is given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31665635/16310741

Comment: @CharchitAgarwal I understand what happens in the SO post you've linked. That makes sense to me. Queues have limited size. I've also found the specific part related to my problem in the documentation you sent. However, I still don't understand _why_ is that, as in, why would anyone design the Queue to behave this way? It makes no sense especially if there is only ever a single process involved. Also, as you've said, there is still the anomaly that the process doesn't hang/sleep if the queue is sufficiently small. Perhaps the data is stored in a simple buffer until it gets too large?

Comment: "It makes no sense especially if there is only ever a single process involved." - it makes no sense to *use* a queue like this in the first place. Inter-process communication queues are not designed for a single process to dump gigantic amounts of data into them and then throw the whole queue away without ever using it to communicate with another process.

Comment: @user2357112 I never intended to use the mp.Queue for this purpose. I'm debugging a piece of code that does use multiprocessing and one of these processes, which uses Queues to communicate tasks to other processes, hangs when the other processes terminate, the queue doesn't get consumed, and _it gets large enough_. That's the curious part I was trying to understand. So I went and constrained all the code into this simple minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand what happens in the SO post you've linked. That makes sense to me. Queues have limited size

Not exactly, queues are simply a higher-level implementation of pipes that allow multiple readers and writers simultaneously. It is these underlying pipes that have a limited size which is abstracted when implementing queues.

> However, I still don't understand why is that, as in, why would anyone design the Queue to behave this way? It makes no sense especially if there is only ever a single process involved

It is more of a design *consequence* than it is a design *choice*, and I'll touch more on this later. As to why queues behave this way even when you're transferring data through a single process, it's because queues simply cannot know which process will be the one consuming items. If you're exclusively only going to put and retrieve items from a single process, then you shouldn't be using a `multiprocessing.Queue` anyway since it's specially created for inter-process communication (consider using `threading.Queue` instead).

> Also, as you've said, there is still the anomaly that the process doesn't hang/sleep if the queue is sufficiently small. Perhaps the data is stored in a simple buffer until it gets too large?

The buffer is implemented through a `collections.deque` and by default, these have infinite size (only restricted by the physical memory your machine has). The problem happens when the background "feeder" thread attempts to flush the data from the buffer to the pipe (it is after this that the data is actually put in the "queue"). When the pipe becomes full, all calls to put data inside the pipe (through methods [`send`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection.send) and equivalent [`send_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection.send_bytes)) will hang until the other end of the pipe removes some data (this happens internally when you call `queue.get()`). When this deadlock happens, the feeder thread can no longer respond to the exit condition being set as true by the main thread (it does this by putting a sentinel at the end of the buffer to signal the thread to exit when the queue is being garbage collected).

This is important because even though the feeder thread is daemonic, the main thread will attempt to join it by default so the queue can be gracefully closed. And because the feeder thread is stuck attempting to empty the buffer, it will never join until someone does `queue.get()` enough times that the buffer can be emptied.

This also explains why the anomaly happens in your case. Basically, if the size of the items you put in a queue is less than or equal to the max size allowed by the pipe, then the feeder thread can empty the buffer right away without waiting for someone to do `queue.get()` and deadlocking (so the process will not hang even if you didn't do `queue.get()` if the amount of data you put in the queue is small). This is essentially what the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665328/python-3-multiprocessing-queue-deadlock-when-calling-join-before-the-queue-is-em/31665635#31665635) I linked to was trying to explain.

If it's all still too abstract then you can use a similar version of your code to replicate how the feeder thread gets blocked and what the maximum size of the pipes on your machine are. Hopefully, this helps clear things up a bit:

```
import multiprocessing


def make_pipe(size):
    """
    Function to check the maximum data a pipe can store. Try inputting a high value for arg size.
    """

    w, r, = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    for i in range(1, size):
        print(i)
        w.send(i)  # If the argument size is high enough, this will eventually deadlock and the process will hang
    return w, r


w, r = make_pipe(10000)
print('done')
```

Comment: "The problem happens when the background feeder thread..." - this is the crucial bit of information for me. The answer you linked mentions nothing apparent about a new thread being associated with a mp.Queue. Thank you for your in-depth description of the problem. I now believe I understand what is happening. +1